# order_totals in sales email template being wrapped in a table

Tags: email, email-templates

I'm trying to modify the layout a bit for the "new sale" email, specifically the order totals area. From the sales.xml file, I see that there's 4 templates being used:

**email/order/items.phtml**

**email/order/items/order/default.phtml**

**email/order/totals/wrapper.phtml**

**sales/order/totals.phtml**

In **items.phtml** the **order_totals** block gets called by **echo $this->getChildHtml('order_totals')** which then seems to load the template from **wrapper.phtml**. The problem that I'm having right now is that the call to **getChildHtml()** seems to wrap the contents from **wrapper.phtml** in another table, which I can't seem to find in the templates at all. Unfortunately, this is the table that I need to make modifications to. Does anyone know if that's in an actual template or is magento building that table dynamically? If it is dynamic, is there a way to add information to the table like whats being done in sales.xml with action methods like **setLabelProperties**? Any direction or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your help!